# how to change the sender email credentials according to the user of application in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

*I want to give different sender email credentials according to the user of application in rails which will be fetched from database.*

Comment: Are you using `ActionMailer` in rails to send the mail? Can you show your mailer? and how do you call it when wanting to send the mail?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `ActionMailer`, you can to set 'from':

```
fetch_sender = Object.select(:email, :name).find(id)
mail(from: "#{fetch_sender.name} <#{fetch_sender.email}>", to: 'Receiver <example@receiver.com>', subject: 'Something')
```

**Example for ActionMailer class:**

app/mailers/custom_mailer.rb

```
class CustomMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def custom(sender, receiver)
    mail(from: "#{sender.name} <#{sender.email}>", to: "#{receiver.name} <#{receiver.email}>", subject: 'Something')
  end
end
```

For sending

```
CustomMailer.custom(sender, receiver).deliver
```

**P.s.** If you have sidekiq or something else, yo may use `deliver_now` or `deliver_later`

Comment: even after changing mail method as given above.the mails are sent from mail id given in development.rb file.

Comment: can you check your SMTP provider credential?

Comment: @mamatha can you please provide ActionMailer model? Moreover, I added example to my answer.

Comment: `def self.send_email(from_email_id,to_email_id,subject,description) 
  message = Message.new  
        message.subject =  subject  
        message.description = description  
        message.to_user_id = to_email_id  
        message.from_user_id = from_email_id  
       
        server_response = NotificationMailer.send_mail(message).deliver!     end`

Comment: @mamatha What is in NotificationMailer? You can add this to your question via update.